# What is the maximum length for a Callback URL for Twilio

Tags: twilio

When making a Twilio call and specifying the callback URL (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter), it appears my callback URL is getting truncated to 148 characters when the POST back to the server occurs.  I can put the full URL in POSTMAN and emulate the request and it works fine.

I couldn't find a length limit in the Twilio API documentation and need to know if this is an actual limit.  The full URL (one example is 195 characters long) shows up in the Call Log on the twilio.com, but my server is only getting the 148 characters (including protocol, host, port), so the request is failing.

I am writing a Twilio proxy for our system to handle all common processing centrally before relaying the callback.  I need the extra length on the URL to pass a base64 encoded end-point (with non-URL friendly characters translated).  I am considering a different algorithm to shorten the URL, but I really want to keep this optimized and simple.

Do Twilio callback URLs (for calls, statuses, etc.) have a 148 character limit?

UPDATE: My code was rejecting the incoming Twilio request because the Twilio signature validation was failing (see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/44) and I returned a 400 Bad Request to Twilio because of the failed validation.  Twilio was sending the **untruncated** URL at that point.  It appears that Twilio retried the same request limiting the URL to 148 characters after it received the 400.  The request was not failing in my local test because the Twilio signature validation succeeds always for local requests.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I work at Twilio and I am going to go find that out for you.

Comment: @philnash I updated the question after discovering more on my end.  I have my solution, but if you find any info that confirms my conclusions, feel free to post as the answer.

Comment: To the downvoter, I edited my question and cleaned it up a bit.  Could you please either remove the downvote or comment on what is lacking?  Thanks

Comment: @philnash - not sure if you want to follow it, but I submitted a Twilio support issue for the inconsistent calculation of X-Twilio-Signature in regards to including port or not https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/810391

Comment: This is a good question, the answer should be part of documentation, eventually have a link here.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for all the information here and that you've sent to support as well. As they said in the response, we have a bug in the signature calculation which the engineering teams are aware of. Your case has been added to that bug as well, so hopefully we will see a fix soon.

Comment: so what is the answer?